# how to create curved dialog layout?

Tags: java, android, layout, dialog, rounded-corners

i want to create curved layout for dialog like this one , i found this image on personal blog for designing . [image]

i searched on web but found nothing , i want to create exact same layout . i know how to create round circle with drawable , i don't have idea how can i create that curve that is in middle of this card .

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is closer to what you want :

1 - The full article: [How I drew custom shapes in bottom bar](https://proandroiddev.com/how-i-drew-custom-shapes-in-bottom-bar-c4539d86afd7)

[image]

2 - **XML** :

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#8F8F8F"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/customBottomBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="fill_vertical|center_horizontal"
        app:rippleColor="#fff" />

    <app.example.CurvedView
        android:id="@+id/customBottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_background">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Call With"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </app.example.CurvedView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

3 - **JAVA** :

```
public class CurvedView extends RelativeLayout {
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // the coordinates of the first curve
    private Point mFirstCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();

    private Point mSecondCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();

    public CurvedView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CurvedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CurvedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
       // setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_background);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // get width and height of navigation bar
        // Navigation bar bounds (width & height)
        int mNavigationBarWidth = getWidth();
        int mNavigationBarHeight = getHeight();
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the start point before curve
        /**
         * the CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS represent the radius of the fab button
         */
        int CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 256 / 2;
        mFirstCurveStartPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
        mFirstCurveEndPoint.set(mNavigationBarWidth / 2, CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4));
        // same thing for the second curve
        Point mSecondCurveStartPoint = mFirstCurveEndPoint;
        mSecondCurveEndPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);

        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 1st control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4), mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mSecondCurveControlPoint1.set(mSecondCurveStartPoint.x + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mSecondCurveStartPoint.y);
        mSecondCurveControlPoint2.set(mSecondCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4)), mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x, mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mSecondCurveControlPoint1.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mSecondCurveControlPoint2.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mSecondCurveEndPoint.x, mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.lineTo(0, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution but it is giving me just rectangle , there is no arc in middle of rectangle . have you done any thing special in @drawable/rounded_background ?

Comment: thanks , its done . i had made some mistake it was why i was not getting proper shape .